# AWS Cloudwatch log windows issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to setup the cloudwatch logs for my windows EC2 instance it's a 2008 r2 server with EC2Config of 4.x version.

1.Instance has roll attached to it with full cloud watch access. 
2.Just to be on the safe side I have tried with the Access key and Secret as well.

The default log works well with the cloudwatch I can see the system event logs but when I try the json from here https://cloudacademy.com/blog/centralized-log-management-with-aws-cloudwatch-part-2-of-3/

I cannot see any logs. This is the json

```html
{
    "EngineConfiguration": {
        "PollInterval": "00:00:15",
        "Components": [
            {
                "Id": "CustomLogs",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CustomLog.CustomLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                   "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\Log",
                    "TimestampFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ff",
                    "Encoding": "UTF-16",
                    "Filter": "ERRORLOG",
                    "CultureName": "en-US",
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "CloudWatchLogs",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatchLogsOutput,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "AccessKey": "",
                    "SecretKey": "",
                    "Region": "ap-southeast-2",
                    "LogGroup": "Database_Logs",
                    "LogStream": "SQL_Server_Logs"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Flows": {
            "Flows": 
            [
                "CustomLogs,CloudWatchLogs"
            ]
        }
    } 
}
```

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you please share the policy you have attached?

Comment: Remove the comma here `"CultureName": "en-US",`. Your Json is not valid.

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan I have used role attached to instance in that "cloudwatch full access" aws managed policy is used

Comment: @Mahdi Didn't worked for me.